# Is it considered code bloat if you have multiple dispatchers in one action creator?

Tags: reactjs, redux, action, react-redux, dispatcher

I have a list of CRUD async action creators. My goal is to update the store but additionally I'd like to do things like redirect the page on a successful POST request and/or provide flash messages. Here's an example:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { addFlashMessage } from '../actions/flash_message_actions';
import { POSTS_URL, POSTS_ENDPOINT } from '../constants/index';

export function deletePost(id) {
  return function (dispatch, getState) {
    dispatch({
      type: DELETE_POST,
    });

    return axios.delete(`${POSTS_URL}/${id}`).then(
      response => {
        dispatch({
          type: DELETE_POST_SUCCESS,
          response,
        });

        dispatch(
          push(POSTS_ENDPOINT)
        );

        dispatch(
          addFlashMessage('Post Deleted')
        );
      },
      error => dispatch({
        type: DELETE_POST_FAILURE,
        error,
      })
    );
  };
}
```

Note the three dispatchers above. All of them have a definite purpose but was just a little hesitant to add so many. Based off the examples I've seen around the web, action creators are usually slim with just one dispatcher.

Additionally is it considered good practice to dispatch an action from a completely different action creator template? Example:

```
import { addFlashMessage } from '../actions/flash_message_actions';
...
dispatch(
  addFlashMessage('Post Deleted')
);
```

Comment: yes to both your questions, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think life would become easier if you implement redux actor so that you don't have to dispatch actions one after the other.

Redux actor takes two argument state and dispatch function and once an action is fired then all the actions inside actor gets trigger at a time you don't have to dispatch action one by one.

refer : http://jamesknelson.com/join-the-dark-side-of-the-flux-responding-to-actions-with-actors/

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example based on my code? I read the article but still a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

It's reasonable.  I recently wrote an article that discusses the pros and cons of using thunks, and particularly using them for multiple dispatches:[Idiomatic Redux: Thoughts on Thunks, Sagas, Abstraction, and Reusability](http://blog.isquaredsoftware.com/2017/01/idiomatic-redux-thoughts-on-thunks-sagas-abstraction-and-reusability/) .